# symfony4 with doctrine-odm : How to add one or more group in aggregation builder

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, doctrine-odm

I am converting mongo queries into symfony4 doctrine ODM queries. In this, doctrine will not accept the multiple group by fields. How to solve the below use case?

**Mongo Queries:**

```
db.Article.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { department: "$department", status : "$status" },
            MIN: { $min: "$salary" },
            MAX: { $max: "$salary" }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Mongo Query Results:**

```
{ "_id" : { "department" : "sales", "status" : 0 }, "MIN" : 100, "MAX" : 5000 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "sales", "status" : 1 }, "MIN" : 10000, "MAX" : 16500 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "IT", "status" : 1 }, "MIN" : 5000, "MAX" : 5000 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "DOCTOR", "status" : 1 }, "MIN" : 20000000, "MAX" : 20000000 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "IAS", "status" : 1 }, "MIN" : 120000, "MAX" : 120000 }
```

**Symfony4 with doctrine odm :**

```
$qb = $this->createAggregationBuilder($documentClass);
$qb
    ->group()
        ->field('id')
        ->expression('$department')
        ->field('department')
        ->first('$department')
        ->field('status')
        ->first('$status')
        ->field('lowestValue')
        ->min('$salary')
        ->field('highestValue')
        ->max('$salary')
        ->field('totalValue')
        ->sum(1);
```

It will only considered group by field of department alone. I want to group by both department and status based group results.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works with Symfony 3. In ArticleRepository.php file write this lines:

```
$qb = $this->createAggregationBuilder('Document\Article');
$group_expression = $qb->expr()
                       ->field('departement')
                       ->expression('$department')
                       ->field('max')
                       ->expression('$max')
                       ->field('min')
                       ->expression('$min');
$qbf->group()
    ->field('id')
    ->expression($group_expression)
    ->field('department')
    ->first('$department')
    ->field('status')
    ->first('$status')
    ->field('lowestValue')
    ->min('$salary')
    ->field('highestValue')
    ->max('$salary')
    ->field('totalValue')
    ->sum(1);
```